QGIS FMV Plugin - Incorrect start location
I'm trying to use the FMV plugin. My video is displaying in the player but my start location and altitude is incorrect (please see FMV metadata in the attached screenshot). It is displaying in Mexico while the video was captured in South  Africa (around 33 degrees latitude, 24 degrees Longitude, 2000m altitude).


Your sensor Latitude and Longitude point to off the coast off Mexico. Was the location captured correctly?

Yes the location was captured correctly in WG84.
